# Запятая перед "как" . Сравнительный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Кого устраивает Игорь, как помощник?
После "Игорь" она нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна. И Игоря ни с кем не сравнивают - нет сравнительного оборота.

Здесь "как" в значении "в качестве" - в функции, образе, роли.

*Кого устраивает Игорь как помощник?*